# 新しくViewの追加

Tags: swift

ボタンが押されたら現在のViewの上に新たにViewを追加して表示し、画面がタップされたら元の処理に戻るという動きをswiftで書きたいのですが
新たなViewを表示はできるのですが
画面をタップすると現在のViewのボタンを認識してしまい、新たなViewが消える処理が適応されず困っています。

なにかよい解決方法をご存じの方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか？

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var myimage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mybutton1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var mybutton2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var mybutton3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var mybutton4: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

    var oView:UIView!
    var onandoff:Bool!


    func ansview(bool:Bool){
        oView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,400,400))
        oView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        oView.alpha = 0.5
        oView.layer.position = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.width/2,self.view.frame.height/2)
        oView.hidden = bool
        self.view.addSubview(oView)
    }



    var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44]
    var names = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44]

    var result:[Int] = []
    var randomquiz:[Int] = []
    var cnt = 4
    var quiz = 1
    var correctanswer : Int?
    var named : [Int] = []
    var truecount:Int = 0
    var idx:Int? = 0;
    var name1:String?
    var name2:String?
    var name3:String?
    var name4:String?
    var qcount = 0;



    func randomq(){

        for (var i=0;i<cnt; i++){
            idx! = Int(arc4random()) % (array.count-1)
            result.append(array[idx!])
            array.removeAtIndex(idx!)
            named.append(result[i])
        }


        name1 = names[named[0]]
        name2 = names[named[1]]
        name3 = names[named[2]]
        name4 = names[named[3]]



        mybutton1?.setTitle(name1, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        mybutton2?.setTitle(name2, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        mybutton3?.setTitle(name3, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        mybutton4?.setTitle(name4, forState: UIControlState.Normal)


        for (var i=0;i<quiz; i++){
            var idx2 : Int? = Int(arc4random()) % result.count
            randomquiz.append(result[idx2!])
            result.removeAtIndex(idx2!)
            array.removeAtIndex(idx2!)
        }


        var str : String = String(randomquiz[0]) + ".jpg"
        myimage?.image = UIImage(named: str)



        correctanswer = Int(randomquiz[0])
    }


    func judge(num:Int){
        qcount++;
        ansview(false)
        if(num == correctanswer){
            NSLog("true")
            truecount++
        }
        if(qcount == 5){
            next()
        }


    }

    func next(){
        var appdel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appdel.conect = truecount

        let end : AnyObject! = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("end")
        self.presentViewController(end as! UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }



    @IBAction func button1(sender: UIButton) {
        judge(named[0])
        result.removeAll()
        randomquiz.removeAll()
        named.removeAll()
        self.randomq()

    }

    @IBAction func button2(sender: AnyObject) {
        judge(named[1])
        result.removeAll()
        randomquiz.removeAll()
        named.removeAll()
        self.randomq()
    }

    @IBAction func button3(sender: AnyObject) {
        judge(named[2])
        result.removeAll()
        randomquiz.removeAll()
        named.removeAll()
        self.randomq()


    }

    @IBAction func button4(sender: AnyObject) {
        judge(named[3])
        result.removeAll()
        randomquiz.removeAll()
        named.removeAll()
        self.randomq()

    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        label2.text = "What is my name?"

        randomq()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: 「新たにViewを追加して表示」のViewは、`oView`のことですか、それとも`end`のことですか？

Comment: 度々すみません　
oViewを表示したいと考えております。
四択が出る→ボタンタップ→oViewで正解を表示→画面タップ→oView非表示→次の問題へ
という動きになります。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: `UIView`のプロパティ`userInteractionEnabled`は、デフォルトで`true`になっており、プログラマが変更を加えていなければ、下の層のボタンがタッチイベントを受け取ることはありません。なので、`oView`の実装について、はしょらずにコードを掲示してくださらないと、意味のある回答はできないでしょう。

Comment: コードはこれが現在の全部です。
あとは、エントリー画面と、結果表示用の画面があるだけでこれのみが本体になります。

Comment: でしたら、`oView`を非表示にする、あるいは消去する実装がないので、消えないのはとうぜんですよね？「画面をタップすると現在のViewのボタンを認識してしまい」は、勘違いということだと思われます。